# threads in a servlet Google appengine Java (for serializing data from XML to blob, pipedinput, pipedoutput)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How does one know when a Thread one started in a Google Appengine 
servlet has completed its assigned tasks.

I am using pipedinput and pipedoutput to get information put XML
into a Blob.  That is the XML Serializer outputs to one end of the pipe. 
 A thread
reads the other end  of the pipe and puts data into the Blob.

I know that one must use the ThreadFactory, newThread function to activate the thread
One cannot use the standard technique from Java of calling `Thread.start()`.

```
T TT;
TT = new T();
java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory TF;
TF = com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
TF.newThread(TT);
```

Here is how I declare and create my Runnable:

```
class T implements Runnable {
public void run(){
FileWriteChannel writeChannel=null;
try {
```

Here is the code to create the Thread.  Note that when I declare type T to
implement the Thread, I get the security exception below:

```
class T implements Runnable {
public void run(){
FileWriteChannel writeChannel=null;
try {
...
```

If I start up a class that extends Thread, Google Appengine gives me  run time error.
If I do a "implements" runnable, that is TT in the example above, is an instance
of an ojbect thwt inmpelements Thread, then, I do not have access to the join
capability, which is defined in the Thread class, but not the runnable.

```
Thread Error java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")     at
java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:375)
    at
java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:565)
    at
java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at


com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:56)
    at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:131)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)*
```

I am doing the  read from the PipedInputStream in a separate thread because
of the statement in the API documentation for PipedInputStream:
 "A piped input stream should be connected to a piped output stream; the piped input 
stream then provides whatever data bytes are written to the piped output stream. 
Typically, data is read from a PipedInputStream object by one thread and data is 
written to the corresponding PipedOutputStream by some other thread. 
Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, 
as it may deadlock the thread. "

Dr. Laurence Leff  Associate Professor of Computer Science,
Western Illinois University, Macomb IL 61455  on sabbatical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually get a `Thread` from `TF.newThread(TT)`. Try calling `join()` on it. Try this:

```
Thread myThread= TF.newThread(TT);
myThread.join();
```

Also note: `currentRequestThreadFactory()` creates threads scoped to the current request. Side effects of such threads is that they cannot outlive request as [docs state](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#currentRequestThreadFactory%28%29):

`Returns a ThreadFactory that will create threads scoped to the current request. These threads will be interrupted at the end of the current request and must complete within the request deadline.`